# Sign in with Apple Using Firebase + Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I have developed feature of Sign in with Apple for iOS using firebaseAuth. Usually it is working fine. but in some scenario it throws crash error : https://prnt.sc/do6XuXsJf-mo

I found this crash in Firebase Crashalytics.

Does any one know, how to solve this error crash? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: (not a downvoter)
Please don't post screenshots of error messages, your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code) --- That also is a good moment to search for the error message, as it likely was covered before.